# Composition of two continuous functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

There are many answers to this question on this site using $\epsilon-\delta$ approach. However, I am hoping to find a solution through a different method. My textbook defines continuity as: $f: D\rightarrow R$ is uniformly continuous if for two sequences ${u_n}$ and ${v_n}$ in $D$ we have that if $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(u_n-v_n) =0$ then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(f(u_n)-f(v_n)) =0$.

I tried $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(fg(u_n)-fg(v_n)) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} fg(u_n)-\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}fg(v_n)=f[\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(u_n)]-f[\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}g(v_n)]$

but not sure where to go after this...

Comment: I don't understand. Are you interested in continuity or in uniform continuity?

Comment: Continuity is enough - I know the definition implied uniform continuity. Was hoping there was a way to prove this through this methodology.

Comment: The topological definition of continuity makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$\eqalign{
  & |f(g({u_n})) - f(g({v_n}))| = |f(g({u_n})) - f(g(v)) + f(g(v)) + f(g({v_n})) - f(g(u)) + f(g(u))|  \cr 
  &  \leqslant |f(g({u_n})) - f(g(u))| + |f(g({v_n})) - f(g(v))| + |f(g(u)) - f(g(v))|  \cr 
  &  \leqslant \varepsilon /2 + \varepsilon /2 + 0 \cr} $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n,p_n$ be seq. s.t. we have $x_n -p_n \to 0 \ \Rightarrow g(x_n) - g(p_n) \to 0$. Define $y_n = g(x_n), \ z_n= g(p_n)$ then

$$
\lim_n f(y_n) - f(z_n) = \lim_n f(g(x_n)) - f(g(p_n)) = \\ f(\lim_n g(x_n)) - f(\lim_n g(p_n)) = 0 
$$

so $y_n - z_n \to 0 \ \Rightarrow f(y_n) - f(z_n) \to 0 \Rightarrow f(g(x_n)) - f(g(p_n)) \to 0.$

Comment: But this doesn't really use the definition given.

Comment: Sorry, see edit. @conums

Comment: Do we not require that the sequences be the same? i.e. don't we have to use $f(x_n)-f(p_n)$ @Olba12

Comment: @conums No, that would imply g(x)=x$.